# Why does select return when USB cable is unplugged?

Tags: c, usb, embedded-linux

I'm having a problem with some linux c code that reads from ttyUSB ports using select, FD_ISSET, read, etc. My modem uses an FTDI serial to USB cable for input. The problem is that select unblocks when the USB cable is unplugged. Is there a way to prevent it from doing that?

```
count = 0;
while ( g_running ) {
   FD_ZERO(&readFdSet);
   maxfd = 0;
   numTransPorts = 0;
   logger( DEBUG, "Begin g_running loop - %d", count );
   for ( i = 0; i < MAX_CONFIG_PORTS; i++ ) {
      if ( configPorts[i].commType == 1 && configPorts[i].pttyHost != NULL ) {
         FD_SET( configPorts[i].pttyHost->fd, &readFdSet );
         logger( DEBUG, "FD_SET - fd=%d, index=%d", configPorts[i].pttyHost->fd, i );
         if ( configPorts[i].pttyHost->fd >= maxfd ) {
            maxfd = configPorts[i].pttyHost->fd;
         }
         numTransPorts++;
      }
   }
   maxfd++; // add one because select check a range to n-1 file descriptors
   if ( maxfd != 0 ) { // indicates no ports are available
      logger( DEBUG, "Calling select() with %d ports and maxfd of %d", numTransPorts, maxfd );
      logger( INFO, "Waiting for input ..." );
      select( maxfd, &readFdSet, NULL, NULL, NULL ); // blocking until one available
      if( result == -1 ){
         logger( INFO, "select() error. errno: %d", errno );
      } else if ( result > 0 ){
         for ( i = 0; i < MAX_CONFIG_PORTS; i++ ) {
            if ( FD_ISSET( configPorts[i].pttyHost->fd, &readFdSet ) ) { // input is available
               logger( INFO, "Input on port %s", configPorts[i].pttyHost->serialPath );
               result = serialPortRead( buffer, configPorts[i].pttyHost->fd );
               if ( result <= 0 ) {
                  // there was an error due to the file descriptor. It
                  // probably indicates that the tty ports are no longer available
               }
            }
         }
      } else {
         logger ( INFO, "select() returns 0" );
      }
   }
   count++;
}
```

serialPortRead:

```
int serialPortRead( char *buf, int serialHandle ) {
   //char ch;
   char *ptr;
   int res = 0;
   int bytesRead = 0;
   int i;

   logger( TRACE, "TRACE: serialPortRead() with fd = %d", serialHandle );

   ptr = buf;

   // try 3 times
   for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
      while ( (res = read( serialHandle, ptr, 1 )) > 0 ) { // read 1 byte at a time
         if ( *ptr == 0x0d ) { //there is 0x0d as a terminate byte from ECR
            break;
         }
         ptr += res;
      }
      if ( res < 0 && errno == EAGAIN ) {
         continue;
      } else {
         break;
      }
   }

   *ptr = 0x00; // set 0x00 as a terminate byte
   //   pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_serial_trans_mutex);
   if ( res < 0 ) {
      // if res is -1, there is an error
      bytesRead = -1;
      logger( DEBUG, "serialPortRead error. errno = %d", errno );
   } else {
      bytesRead = (int) (ptr - buf);
      logger( DEBUG, "serialPortRead %d bytes", bytesRead );
   }

   return bytesRead;
}
```

When the USB cable is unplugged, select() unblocks, implying input is available, FD_ISSET returns true. read(), in serialPortRead, will return with zero bytes having been read. It then loops back to the select() which unblocks again saying input is available, and so on. Thus, you get a infinite loop of select(), FD_ISSET returning true, the fd never gets cleared, read returns 0 and so on. How can I fix this? The behavior I would expect is that select does not falsely unblock when there is not really anything to read?

NOTE: when select unblocks it returns a positive number

Comment: are you sure that select returning means 'input is available' only? afaik it also can mean 'there's an error', wh8ich is exactly the case here.

Comment: When read returns 0, there's nothing more to read, so you have to take the fd out of the set you're selecting for. When an error occurs, you get one chance to have the error delivered to you; once you've been informed of the error, you have to close the fd and stop selecting it rather than try to keep on selecting and reading.

Comment: I guess the behavior that I am hoping for is just not the way it works. When the app starts, it looks at the USB devices plugged in and opens them for input. The configuration should not change unless they are unplugged by accident. I would like it to just not do anything. Then, when the cable is plugged back in, input could be received without interuption.

Comment: @user1100151 - that wouldn't work anyway - you would need to re-open the (new) tty device created when the usb-serial is plugged back in.  Indeed, if you try to keep the old one open, it's likely that the re-plugged converter will get a different name!  The kind of behavior you seem to expect is what would happen if the rs232 cable is unplugged from the converter, but unplugging the usb end of the converter is nearly comparable to opening the computer case and yanking the UART card out of the bus (though in the USB case it's designed so that the hardware and system software survive this)

Answer (score 5):

`select()` is returning because there is information to read - in this case, the fact that the file descriptor has reached "end of file".  This is indicated by `read()` returning `0`.

When `read()` returns `0`, you should be closing the corresponding file descriptor.

Comment: I thnk you are right in that the fd should be closed, which I do. However, I was hoping there was some way to prevent select from unblocking in the first place. Then, when the cable is re-plugged, the app would still be in a state to receive input. An RS232 cable, for instance, can be unplugged and then plugged back in without triggering an event.

Comment: @user1100151: That's just not how USB ttys work - when you unplug and replug a USB tty, it's the entire serial port device that's disappearing and reappearing.  The kernel has no way of knowing if it's the same USB device reappearing or a different one, so it creates a new device node on each plug event.  With wired-in RS232 serial ports the serial device itself never goes away.